# Multiple footnotemarks inside display math mode

Tags: hyperref, footnotes, counters, displaystyle

I'm using `footnotemark` and `footnotetext` inside an equation in display style in math mode. I already know that in order for this to work  you need to write the `footnotetext` outside the environment, but the thing is I have more than one `footnotemark` in the environment, but every `footnotetext` thinks it's linked to the last `footnotemark`. I've tried specifying the number in each `footnotetext[n]`, but this appears to change just the number displayed, not the mark linked to the corresponding `footnotemark`. I've also tried to modify the counter of `footnote` before `footnotetext` appears, but, again, this just changes the displayed number!

For example,

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
 \usepackage[spanish]{babel}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{mathtools}
 \usepackage{amsthm}
 \usepackage{mathrsfs} 
 \usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
 \usepackage{relsize}
 \usepackage{marvosym} 
 \usepackage{graphicx} 
 \graphicspath{ {./images/} } 
 \usepackage[official]{eurosym}

 \usepackage[hang]{footmisc} % used only for hanged style
 \usepackage{fnpct}% fix multiple footnotes separator
 \usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}% hyperlinks to footnotes
 \hypersetup{allcolors=blue}

 \usepackage{footnotebackref}% hyperlinks to text, loads hyperref


 \title{Super lorem ipsum}

 \author{}
 \date{}

 \setlength{\parskip}{10pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}
 \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}

 \makeatletter
 \LetLtxMacro{\BHFN@Old@footnotemark}{\@footnotemark}

 \renewcommand*{\@footnotemark}{%
    \refstepcounter{BackrefHyperFootnoteCounter}%
    \xdef\BackrefFootnoteTag{bhfn:\theBackrefHyperFootnoteCounter}%
    \label{\BackrefFootnoteTag}%
    \BHFN@Old@footnotemark}
 \makeatother

 \makeatletter 
      \renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
          \renewcommand\@makefnmark{%
           \mbox{{\normalfont%
             \hyperref[\BackrefFootnoteTag]{\@thefnmark}}}.}%
               \BHFN@OldMakefntext{#1}}%
 \makeatother

  \begin{document}

   \maketitle

 \[1=1\footnotemark\Rightarrow 2=2\footnotemark\Rightarrow 3=3\footnotemark\]

 \footnotetext{This should be linked to 1=1}
 \footnotetext{This should be linked to 2=2}
 \footnotetext{This is linked, along with the other footnotes, to 3=3}

\end{document}
```

Is there anyway to specify or change the mark counter so the first instance of `footnotetext` is linked to the first instance of `footnotemark` in the environment? I'm willing to do it for every instance of `footnotetext` if that's what it takes! Cheers in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide an example of small but complete document, which reproduce your problem. In general you can give names to `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` link to them.

Comment: Can you point me to a webpage or a document so I can learn how to do it?

Comment: This is done by decreasing the value of the footnote counter by the required amount before entering the first `\footnotetext`.  (It will increase by 1 each time it's called after that use.)  I know this has been asked before, but haven't located it.

Comment: When I was first starting out in my research career, I received two particularly good pieces of advice about writing papers: "First, put all secondary and supplementary stuff into footnotes. Second, when you think your paper is done, delete all the footnotes." Seriously, what's so intricate or elaborate about your display-math material that it needs to be marked up with a host of footnotes? If this material is truly important, do *not* put it into footnotes, where all but the most dedicated and diligent readers will be apt to ignore it. Instead, put it right into the document's main body.

Comment: I'm elaborating a document with solutions to some exercises done by my students. I use footnotes mainly to say obvious stuff, such that we're taking into account some variable isn't zero or that there are other ways to do it that are equally right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well footnote links between `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` are difficult ;-). As soon as you have a row of `\footnotemark` hyperref loose track of the names.

You can try it with a sort of explicit labeling:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand\storefnmark[1]
 { 
   \tl_new:c{g__darsen_fnmark.#1_tl}%
   \tl_gset:cx{g__darsen_fnmark.#1_tl}{{\Hy@footnote@currentHref}{\int_use:N\c@footnote}}
 }
  
\newcommand\restorefnmark[1]
 {
   \tl_gset:Nx\Hy@footnote@currentHref
    {\exp_last_unbraced:Nv\use_i:nn {g__darsen_fnmark.#1_tl}}
   \setcounter{footnote}{\exp_last_unbraced:Nv\use_ii:nn {g__darsen_fnmark.#1_tl}}
 }  
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\footnote{a}\quad \footnotemark\storefnmark{b}\quad \footnotemark\storefnmark{c}
\lipsum[1]
\footref{fn:b}

\restorefnmark{b}\footnotetext{\label{fn:b}b}%
\restorefnmark{c}\footnotetext{c}
\end{document}
```

As an alternative you can try the new output routine code which tries to keep track automatically. But be aware that it is not yet compatible with everything (e.g. it errors currently with the hang option of footmisc):

```
\DocumentMetadata{testphase={new-OR}}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\footnote{a}\quad \footnotemark\quad \footnotemark
\lipsum[1]
\footref{fn:b}

\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}\footnotetext{\label{fn:b}b}%
\stepcounter{footnote}\footnotetext{c}
\end{document}
```

I didn't try with your backref code and personnally I would advise against it. It can't handle cases where there is more than one mark connected to a footnote. It is better to go back with the keys of your pdf viewer.

Comment: I actually agree with you that backref isn't advisable in general. I only use it when the document I'm writing is intended to be read by new students, in which case I don't expect them to know you can go back using commands or whatever. Anyway, thanks a lot for your answer!