# Multiple footnotemarks with hyperref are incorrectly referenced

Tags: hyperref, luatex

I have the requirement to place within a caption a footnote - not only one but as well multiple. I searched for several approaches and found finally the following solution - as MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[pdfa, unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\kant[1-6]
\begin{figure}[H]
Test of a caption with two footnote 
\caption[figure]{%
\protect\footnotemark{} first footnote. 
\protect\footnotemark{}second footnote.}
\end{figure}
%\kant[1]
\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}
\footnotetext{first reference footnote}
\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\footnotetext{second footnote }
\kant
\end{document}
```

This solution compiles well with `lualatex 1.17.0` and `Hyperref v7.00v`. The main problem I see is clicking on the first footnote reference. The page scrolls to "nowhere". When I click on the second footnote counter the page scrolls correctly and displays the footnote properly.

Does this work as intended or do I need to adapt something more?

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/696095/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Hmmm... I have no clue how to respond. I'll try it as an answer to my post and as a reference to your provided answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I first tried using `\refstepcounter`, but inside `\footnotetext` is too late and before will link to the location where `\footnotetext` was created.  So I created `\footlabel` to define the `\hypertarget` correctly.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[pdfa, unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\makeatletter
\def\footlabel{%
  %\edef\@currentlabel{\thefootnote}%
  \edef\@currentHref{footnote.\the\c@footnote}%
  \raisebox{\baselineskip}[0pt]{\hypertarget{\@currentHref}{}}% adjust aim up
  \label}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\kant[1-6]
Note that aim point does not include number\footnote{test}
\begin{figure}[H]
Test of a caption with two footnote 
\caption[figure]{% no \protect needed with short caption [figure] in use
\footref{A} first footnote. 
\footref{B} second footnote.}
\end{figure}
%\kant[1]
\stepcounter{footnote}%
\footnotetext{\footlabel{A}first reference footnote}
\stepcounter{footnote}%
\footnotetext{\footlabel{B}second footnote }
\kant
\end{document}
```

Comment: I like your solution since it requires just one additional macro and the rest of the handling seems simple. Thx for your proposal

Comment: this produce warnings `pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{Hfootnote.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored `

Comment: Inspecting the log files after @UlrikeFischer mentioned it I get similar (but not same) warning `warning  (pdf backend): ignoring duplicate destination with the name 'Hfootnote`

Comment: This is a bug in the hyperref version `\footnotetext`.  Unfortunately, I can't find the source to fix it (hyperref is becoming increasingly unreadable).  Without this bug, one could use `\label` instead of `\footlabel`.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness: I've tested as well the sample linked from @UlrikeFischer. The warnings are the same as in this provided solution.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: Thank you very much for the provided solution. I too test in a more broader spectrum. One tiny question - not really important, nevertheless: If I compare the resulting PDFs than the comparator recognize that the footnotes are shifted little bit to the top. Is the measurement `\baselineskip` for the footnotes appropriate measure? Just a q out of curiosity.

Comment: It is fontsize dependent.  You can try `\ht\strutbox` as well, but `\baselineskip` looks like the regular footnote anchor.

Comment: I played around a bit. I think you have to use `\footnotesep` for the footnote - which seems to have the same definition as `\ht\strutbox`. I don't think you could see the difference in the output in the example given. I only noticed it with multiple footnotes.  Basically, the height of the footnote is somehow adjusted. So I guess you have to choose between the correct height of the boxed footnote and scrolling to the destination. Thx for the hint and I'm happy to have found a working solution.

Comment: If using `\raisebox` is changing the spacing (rather than just the hyperref target) add the optional argument [0pt] (as now shown).